# CNTK: How do I initialize LSTM hidden state?

Tags: cntk

I'm trying convert a working image captioning CNN-LSTM network from TensorFlow to CNTK, and have what I think is a correctly trained model, but am having trouble figuring out how to extract predictions from the final trained CNTK model.

This is the general architecture I'm working with:
[image]
This is my CNTK model:

```
def create_lstm_model(image_features, text_features):
    embedding_dim = 512
    hidden_dim = 512
    cell_dim = 512
    vocab_dim = 77

    image_embedding = Embedding(embedding_dim)
    text_embedding = Embedding(embedding_dim)
    lstm_classifier = Sequential([Stabilizer(),
                                  Recurrence(LSTM(hidden_dim)),
                                  Recurrence(LSTM(hidden_dim)),
                                  Stabilizer(),
                                  Dense(vocab_dim)]) 

    embedded_images = BatchNormalization()(image_embedding(image_features))
    embedded_text = text_embedding(text_features)
    lstm_input = C.plus(embedded_images, embedded_text)
    lstm_input = C.dropout(lstm_input, 0.5)
    output = lstm_classifier(lstm_input)    

    return output
```

I'm providing my data in CTF format, with fixed caption sequence sizes of 40, using this structure:

```
def create_reader(path, is_training):
    return MinibatchSource(CTFDeserializer(path, StreamDefs(
        target_tokens = StreamDef(field='target_tokens', shape=vocab_len, is_sparse=True),
        input_tokens = StreamDef(field='input_tokens', shape=vocab_len, is_sparse=True),
        image_features = StreamDef(field='image_features', shape=image_features_dim, is_sparse=False)
    )), randomize = is_training, max_sweeps = INFINITELY_REPEAT if is_training else 1)
```

Aside: the reason for three streams of data - I have an input image feature vector (last 2048-dim layer of a pre-trained ResNet), a sequence of input text tokens, and a sequence of output text tokens. So basically my CTF file, in terms of sequences, looks like:

```
0 | target_token_0  | input_token_0 | input_image_feature_vector (2048-dim)
0 | target_token_1  | input_token_1 | empty array of 2048 zeros
0 | target_token_2  | input_token_2 | empty array of 2048 zeros
...
0 | target_token_40 | input_token_40 | empty array of 2048 zeros
1 | target_token_0  | input_token_0 | input_image_feature_vector (2048-dim)
1 | target_token_1  | input_token_1 | empty array of 2048 zeros
1 | target_token_2  | input_token_2 | empty array of 2048 zeros
...
1 | target_token_40 | input_token_40 | empty array of 2048 zeros
```

Basically, I couldn't figure out how to slice & splice two sequences together in CNTK (even though you can splice two tensors easily), so I'm hacking around it by providing only the first element in a sequence with an input 2048-dim image feature vector, and the remaining elements in a sequence with an empty 2048-dim vector of zeros - setup for:

`C.plus(embedded_images, embedded_text)`

in the model above - where the goal is to essentially take the first element of a sequence of 40 `[2048]->[512]` image embeddings and **hack-splice**(TM) it in front of the last 39 elements of a sequence of 40 `[vocab_dim]->[512]` word embeddings. I'm counting on pretty empty `[2048]->[512]` image embeddings being learned for the empty image vectors (2048 zeros), so I'm taking my embedded image sequence and element-wise adding it to my embedded text sequence before all goes into the LSTM. Basically, this:

```
image embedding sequence: [-1, 40, 512]  (e.g., [-1, 0, 512])
text embedding sequence:  [-1, 40, 512]  (e.g., [-1, 1:40, 512)
+
---------------------------------------
lstm input sequence:      [-1, 40, 512]
```

Which brings me to my actual question. Now that I have a model that trains decently well, I'd like to extract caption predictions from the model, basically doing something like this (from this [PyTorch image captioning tutorial](https://github.com/yunjey/pytorch-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/03-advanced/image_captioning/model.py)):

```
def sample(self, features, states=None):
    """Samples captions for given image features (Greedy search)."""
    sampled_ids = []
    inputs = features.unsqueeze(1)
    for i in range(20):                                      # maximum sampling length
        hiddens, states = self.lstm(inputs, states)          # (batch_size, 1, hidden_size), 
        outputs = self.linear(hiddens.squeeze(1))            # (batch_size, vocab_size)
        predicted = outputs.max(1)[1]
        sampled_ids.append(predicted)
        inputs = self.embed(predicted)
        inputs = inputs.unsqueeze(1)                         # (batch_size, 1, embed_size)
    sampled_ids = torch.cat(sampled_ids, 1)                  # (batch_size, 20)
    return sampled_ids.squeeze()
```

The problem is, I can't figure out the CNTK equivalent for getting the hidden state out of an LSTM and pumping it back in next time step:

```
hiddens, states = self.lstm(inputs, states)
```

How does this work in CNTK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function you are looking is `RecurrenceFrom()`. Its documentation contains the following example:

```
Example:
 >>> from cntk.layers import *
 >>> from cntk.layers.typing import *

 >>> # a plain sequence-to-sequence model in training (where label length is known)
 >>> en = C.input_variable(**SequenceOver[Axis('m')][SparseTensor[20000]])  # English input sentence
 >>> fr = C.input_variable(**SequenceOver[Axis('n')][SparseTensor[30000]])  # French target sentence

 >>> embed = Embedding(300)
 >>> encoder = Recurrence(LSTM(500), return_full_state=True)
 >>> decoder = RecurrenceFrom(LSTM(500))       # decoder starts from a data-dependent initial state, hence -From()
 >>> emit = Dense(30000)
 >>> h, c = encoder(embed(en)).outputs         # LSTM encoder has two outputs (h, c)
 >>> z = emit(decoder(h, c, sequence.past_value(fr)))   # decoder takes encoder outputs as initial state
 >>> loss = C.cross_entropy_with_softmax(z, fr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue recently. Below I'm providing a sample code I built to understand how to use `Recurrence` and `RNNStep` objects to obtain forecasts. Note here that the forecasts are just the next period state since this is not transformed in any way. I used an `RNNStep` because it contains fewer parameters which makes it easy to build a simple example. Same logic applies to LSTM.

The first part of the example builds a white noise process to play with (it could be any process):

```
process_dim = 1
n_periods = 100
np.random.seed(0)
x_data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=np.array([0.0], dtype=np.float32),
                                       cov=np.matrix([[0.1]], dtype=np.float32),
                                       size=n_periods).astype(np.float32)
```

Then I build the RNN and sets its parameters in such a way that it is easy to understand its internal computations.

```
x = cntk.sequence.input_variable(shape=process_dim)
initial_state = 10
W = 1
H = 1
b = 1
with cntk.layers.default_options(initial_state=initial_state):
    model = cntk.layers.Recurrence(cntk.layers.RNNStep(shape=process_dim,
                                                       activation=lambda x_: x_,
                                                       init=W,
                                                       init_bias=b))(x)
```

Note1: the argument `init` sets both H and W.
Note 2: if you don't use the `with` statement the initial state is set to 0 which works too.

Let's first look at how to evaluate the RNN one step ahead, i.e. combining the previous period state (initial state in our case) and the current period external input (an entry of `x_data`) to obtain the next state. The script below does that by calling `model.eval()` on some given inputs and then does the actual RNN computations manually to validate the output.

```
x0 = np.array(x_data[0]).reshape((1, 1))
x1 = np.array(x_data[1]).reshape((1, 1))
x2 = np.array(x_data[2]).reshape((1, 1))

h00 = model.eval({x: x0})
h01 = model.eval({x: x1})
h02 = model.eval({x: x2})

print("x0: {}, h00: {}".format(x0, h00))
print("x1: {}, h01: {}".format(x1, h01))
print("x2: {}, h02: {}".format(x2, h02))

# validation
h00_m = initial_state * H + x0[0, 0] * W + b
h01_m = initial_state * H + x1[0, 0] * W + b
h02_m = initial_state * H + x2[0, 0] * W + b

print("validation of state computed manually")
print("x0: {}, h00_m: {}".format(x0[0, 0], h00_m))
print("x1: {}, h01_m: {}".format(x1[0, 0], h01_m))
print("x2: {}, h02_m: {}".format(x2[0, 0], h02_m))
```

Let's now see how to use `model.eval()` to obtain multiple periods ahead forecasts. Again, the script below does that and validates the output.

```
# x0 now contains multiple entries
x0 = np.array(x_data[0:4]).reshape((4, 1))
h1234 = model.eval({x: x0})
print("forecasts obtained by model automatically")
print(h1234)

h01_m = initial_state * H + x0[0, 0] * W + b
h12_m = h01_m * H + x0[1, 0] * W + b
h23_m = h12_m * H + x0[2, 0] * W + b
h34_m = h23_m * H + x0[3, 0] * W + b

print("forecasts computed manually")
print(h01_m)
print(h12_m)
print(h23_m)
print(h34_m)
```

So because `RNNStep` is used inside `Recurrence`, it automatically calls `RNNStep` according to the number of input(s) you provide to the model function. Each time the `RNNStep` is called it receives the previous period state and an entry of the array given to `model.eval()`. This is in line with what happens at training.

Here is some useful documentation of LSTMs and RNNs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/cntk.layers.blocks?view=cntk-py-2.2
Its content is not exactly the same as https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/index.html and in this case it is more useful.

Sorry I cannot help with the ctf part of your question, I have limited knowledge of this and I also have posted a question on this that has yet to be answered.